# Can I prevent specific directory files from being locked by the dotnet.exe process on IIS Windows server?

Tags: .net-core, iis, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I am using CodeDeplpy to deploy several IIS applications on a Windows 2019 server. During the deployment of one of my .Net Core 3.1 applications I noticed this error:

```
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webApi/AutocheckerEntities.dll
```

To solve that I added a line that kills the whole `dotnet.exe` process (see below) in addition to stopping the app pool and the app itself (see below). I added the dotnet kill line as simply stopping the app pool & app did not get around the error.

appstop.ps1:

```
Stop-WebSite 'WebApi'
Stop-WebAppPool (Get-Website -Name WebApi).applicationPool
taskkill /IM "dotnet.exe" /F
```

appspec.yml:

```yaml
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: /
    destination: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webApi
hooks:
   BeforeInstall:
     - location: CodeDeploy/appstop.ps1
       runas: administrator
   ApplicationStart:
     - location: CodeDeploy/appstart.ps1       
       runas: administrator
```

Is there a way to release temporarily the files in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webApi` directory without killing the whole `dotnet.exe` process? I have other dotnet applications on the same server and killing the process can affect those as well.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Hi Sam. There is no problem, at the moment. I was just asking if there is a better  way to "unlock" files that the dotnet runtime uses. At the moment, I kill the whole `dotnet.exe` process to release the files which could affect all sites on the IIS server using dotnet